# White line detection after applying Gaussian Blur and Canny Edge Detection in a low light Image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have two images one is bright and the edge detection works well for that and the white line is clearly visible.

Whereas there is another image which is taken in dark with low light and the white lines are pretty faded and hardly visible.

**Original image**

low light:

[image]

Good Light:

[image]

**Canny Edge Detection**

Low Light

[image]

Good Light

[image]

What Image filters I can apply to both these images so that white line are detected for both the images. I have tried Gray scale and Gaussian Blur followed by canny edge detection but it didn't worked well

**My Code**

```
img = mpimg.imread(filenm)

# first convert to grayscale
grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

#apply gaussian blur before canny edge detection
kernel_size=125
gaussian_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayscale,(kernel_size, kernel_size), 0)

# Canny edge detection threshold ratio 1:3
low_threshold = 50
high_threshold = 150
edges = cv2.Canny(gaussian_blurred, low_threshold, high_threshold)


plt.imshow(edges, cmap='Greys_r')
```

Comment: Better try adaptive thresholding

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Comment: @min2bro your code generated black screen only even in high luminance, can you please check your code again, especially the kernel size `kernel_size=125`! I didn't the same edge as you!